# I get errors when trying to rename files

Tags: powershell

I have files in a folder `C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Projects\files\old\`. I have built a loop to rename them but it doesn't work out:

```
$newfiles = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Projects\files\new\"  

Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $newfiles+"$($entry.Custom_ID).$($file.BaseName).PDF"
```

How do I concatenate properly `$newfiles` to the rename path? I tried everything but keep getting errors:

```
Rename-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-'
```

Comment: It is not allowed to use folder path for new names when renaming files! If you want to move and rename files use Move-Item cmdlet.

Comment: +1 for @autosvet comment...see my answer below...also what is the `$entry variable. How are you getting\setting it?

Answer (score 2):

you need to either copy and rename or move and rename files.using `-whatif` is a good practise because it shows you what is going to happen if you execute a particular command.

Notice also i am using a filter to `get-childitem` to only get the `pdf` files so that i know that the files i am going to rename will only be pdf files. of course if the oldfiles folder only contains pdf files then you dont need to use the filter.

```
$newfiles = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Projects\files\new\"  
$oldfiles = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Projects\files\old\" 


Get-ChildItem -Path $oldfiles -Filter *.pdf | 
 Move-Item -Destination {Join-Path -Path $newfiles -ChildPath "$($entry.Custom_ID).$($_.BaseName).pdf"} -WhatIf
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $oldfiles -Filter *.pdf | 
 copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path -Path $newfiles -ChildPath "$($entry.Custom_ID).$($_.BaseName).pdf"} -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I always concatenate things in Powershell:

```
$newfiles = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Projects\files\new\"  

Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName ("{0}{1}.PDF" -f $newfiles,$($entry.Custom_ID).$($file.BaseName))
```

From experience, this always works.